# TYPO3 : Copy records between browsers

Tags: drag-and-drop, copy, typo3, user-experience, backend

Is it possible or planned to provide the drag&drop way of records coping between different TYPO3 installations ?

I mean something in [Draggables](http://draggables.com/) way with HTML5.

Answer (score 0):

No it's not possible, although idea is very nice. Most probably better place for this question is mailing list of the TYPO3 Core Team.

Comment: The problem would be that both installations do not know anything about each other. So you either have to transfer the whole object (like t3x) or you have to link the installations somehow.

Comment: AFAIK drag&drop is on the list, maybe we can think of something like this once we have basic drag&drop done.

Comment: @pgampe, de facto DnD on the list is easy, that doesn't do much, it just changes `pid` and/or `sorting` of the record. The Fedir's link is brilliant, but much more complicated. That could be done at least with obvious tables like `pages` or `tt_content` but I wouldn't expect that in nearest future.

Comment: Well, it would be the same for all tables (pages is special). But still, you need some exchange format ;)